# Why are my tkinter window objects (OOP tkinter) not BOTH showing?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to learn about tkinter from an OOP point of view so that I can create multiple windows.

I have created two files (main.py and Humanclass.py).

Why are both windows not being created? I thought that I had created a Class and in the main program created 2 instance of that class with different data?

Main.py:

```
import humanclass
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

human1 = humanclass.Human(window, "Jim", "78", "British")

human2 = humanclass.Human(window, "Bob", "18", "Welsh")

window.mainloop()
```

humanclass.py:

```
from tkinter import *


class Human():
    def __init__(self, window, name, age, nation):
        self.window=window
        self.window.geometry("500x200+100+200")
        self.window.title(name)
        self.label1 = Label(self.window, text=age).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.label2 = Label(self.window, text=nation).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.button = Button(self.window, text="Close", width=5, command=self.clicked).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

    def clicked(self):
        self.window.destroy()
```

Any help to show me the errors in my limited understanding would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because window is only one active window, i.e. the root window. If you want to create multiple windows you will need to spawn them off of that root window. Simply assigning things to that window would overwrite whatever was previously there. That's why only your bottom instance is showing. While technically you could get away with implementing threading and running two root windows with two mainloops, it is highly advised not to do that.

What you should do is create Toplevel instances off of the root window. Think of these as like popup windows that are independent. You can make them independent of the root window or have them anchored to it. That way if you close the root window all the Toplevels off of it will close. I suggest you look more into Toplevels and you'll find what you're looking for. You probably want something like this:

Main.py

```
import humanclass
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
# Hides the root window since you will no longer see it
window.withdraw()

human1 = humanclass.Human(window, "Jim", "78", "British")
human2 = humanclass.Human(window, "Bob", "18", "Welsh")


window.mainloop()
```

humanclass.py

```
from Tkinter import *


class Human():
    def __init__(self, window, name, age, nation):
        # Creates a toplevel instance instead of using the root window
        self.window=Toplevel(window)
        self.window.geometry("500x200+100+200")
        self.window.title(name)
        self.label1 = Label(self.window, text=age).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.label2 = Label(self.window, text=nation).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.button = Button(self.window, text="Close", width=5, command=self.clicked).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

    def clicked(self):
        self.window.destroy()
```